# Is it possible to get a full configuration from a namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I am looking for keeping some kind of baseline for everything applied to kubernetes(or just a namespace).

Like versioning microservices in a list and then check that in to github, in case of the need to roll something back.

Comment: consider using https://fluxcd.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* write and deploy an application that `Watch` the resources you are interested in, e.g. all `Deployment`, `Service` and `Ingress`... including all changes, and then store the changes as you want. I can recommend [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) for this kind of service.

However

> Like versioning microservices in a list and then check that in to github, in case of the need to roll something back.

It is more common, and recommended to work the **other way around**, first save your *intended desired state* in **Git**, have an **CICD** service to apply your changes in the cluster or clusters. This way of working is called *Infrastructure as Code*. The new edition of the book [Kubernetes Up&Running](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YP1XSZ9) have a new chapter (18) that describes how to work in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Velero, it is a backup tool for kubernetes. I don’t think it can use git as a backend, but you could add that (or use s3 or similar).